# Multiple MySQL DELETE disabling email notification

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to do four things, but I can only get step 1, 2 and 4 to work if I comment out step 3: (1) Get first_name from the order header to include in email notification, (2) Delete the order header, (3) Delete the Order items, and (4) Send email notification when the order header has been deleted.

The following code does step 1, 2 and 4 only if step 3 is commented out:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// (1) Get first_name
$sql = "SELECT id, first_name FROM Orders where id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$first_name = $data['first_name'];
$last_name = $data['last_name'];

// (2) delete Header record
$sql = "DELETE FROM Orders  WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));

// (3) Delete Order Items
// $sql = "DELETE FROM Order_Items  WHERE id = ?";
// $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// $q->execute(array($id));

// I moved these 2 lines to the bottom as suggested by Martin
Database::disconnect(); 
header("Location: index.php");

// (4) send email notification 
$to = "email address 1";
$email_from = "email address 2";
$today = date("m.d.y");
$body = "";

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"From: {$email_from}\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$subject = "Order record deleted - " 
. $id . " " 
. $first_name  . " " 
. $last_name  . "-" 
. $today;

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

When I un-comment step 3, not only does step 3 not work, but step 4 fails to work as well.

The error log may be of assistance, but I cannot figure out the solution. It says:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id'
```

The error is thrown on the line where the $q->execute(array($id)) appears. The only thing I can figure is that step 1 and step 2 are working on the same table (Orders) so it doesn't mind. But now that I introduce a command on a new table (Order_Items) it gets confused.

Comment: Is that normal if you disconnect your pdo from your database just after the second request and not after the third ?

Comment: `Database::disconnect();
header("Location: index.php");` why is this here? before step 3 this will occur before step 3 and so will interrupt your script logic

Comment: I was going to say same thing with @Martin , it should not be possible you get an error for step 3, while you have Database::disconnect(); header("Location: index.php"); before that

Comment: No that was an edit error in posting this question. It appears correctly in the code. I fixed the above. (If it only it were that easy).

Comment: does your `Order_Items` table have a column called `id`?

Comment: Also, you're still telling PHP to load another file before even reaching the code that sends the email, while headers are not run as soon as discovered, by putting the `header` before the code still makes it very hard to understand your perceived logic here

Comment: @Martin - you are wonderful. Thank you! That was an easy fix. Sorry It is called orders_id. Thank you! Simple questions. I wonder if I should remove this post since the answer was so simple

Comment: @Bricked no, simple answers are only simple because you know what it is. You were stumped an hour ago, so keeping the question and answer should help others in a similar situation discover *Why*

Comment: @Martin (and others) thank you very much for being there. Very helpful service. Thank you

Comment: @Bricked no worries, glad you got the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Does your `Order_Items` table have a column called `id`?

> @Martin - you're a genius. No. It is called orders_id. Thank you!

No, alas [I am no genius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085660/3536236), I simply read the error message:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id'**

*Always read your error messages!!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah but the hours can be long and unforgiving.... I miss the days of Private Eye's....